# Is it possibile to get all types of interface or a map of them?

Tags: typescript

I have created this method that accepts an object with some data and returns an object that is compliant with an interface.

```js
interface FireData {
    id: EventTypes;
    reason?: string;
    error?: string;
}

enum EventTypes {
    eventType1 = "ev1",
    eventType2 = "ev2,
    ...
}

interface EventComposedData {
    key1: string;
    key2: boolean;
    key3: EventTypes;
    "event-value": string;
}

track(fireData: FireData): EventComposedData {
    const composedData = composeSomehowECD(fireData);
    sendTracking(composedData);
}
```

I came in need to send in `fireData`, some data that will override the default values that `composeSomehowECD` will return.

To achieve the keys I did like this:

```
interface FireData {
    id: EventTypes;
    reason?: string;
    error?: string;
    eventData?: {
        [key in keyof EventComposedData]?: any
    }
}
```

So currently when I do

```
track({
    eventData: {
        key1: "4"
    }
});
```

`key1` has type `any`, therefore a wrong value might mess up the final result.
I'd like to understand if there's a way to get or all the types of an interface (to do something like: `[key in keyof EventComposedData]?: typesof EventComposedData`) or a better way to get the couples `key: type`.

Yes, I can actually do something like:

```
interface FireData {
   ...
   eventData: EventComposedData;
}
```

But what if I'd like to allow properties to be used like an index?

I mean:

```
const eventData: { [key in keyof EventComposedData]: any } = {};
eventData["event-value"]: 5

track(eventData);
```

In this case, `event-value` is always `any` as type and we go back to the same problem as above, and I cannot set a specific type instead of any because there are many.
Thank you.

Comment: `[key in keyof EventComposedData]: EventComposedData[key]` would be identical to the original type. Also `Pick` allows you to take some properties from a type, youmight find it usedul

Comment: Didn't know it was possible to do like this, thanks @TitianCernicova-Dragomir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you want to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) here. These allow you to take one object type and change which keys are included, and transform their values. In your case, you want the same type as `EventComposedData`, but with every property made optional.

That looks something like this:

```js
  eventData?: {
    [K in keyof EventComposedData]?: EventComposedData[K]
  };
```

In fact though, there's a predefined mapped type that does this called `Partial`, and you can just use that directly, instead of defining it yourself:

```js
  eventData?: Partial<EventComposedData>;
```

These are equivalent: `Partial` should work fine for you, or you might want to use the mapped type itself if you'd like to do something more complex (require one specific property, or skip some properties).

[TypeScript playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-rRseRJgLaAAWPT1QIgxSkDFYvS4qIkvZE-FpcnG5AsNm2igs6zWZByBaUYqOXyJo384a0bL4f06WpKLM5tH5z5Jig0YusUtx3ZcMl6Sl0OHvaWy6CWHjNiCOzAAKwgz28bwWIvIC87fWTPdSAAYH32B2Mh5m6jmgA)

Comment: Thank you very much! That was what I was looking for. Also, I thought that "key" was specific (like "index") and wasn't replaceble / renameble.